# Не могу использовать WebKit Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: webkitwidgets

Tags: qt, qt5, webkit

Не могу использовать WebKit, ошибка:

```
 Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: webkitwidgets
```

Пробовал использовать webenginewidgets получаю

```
Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: webenginewidgets
```

Вроде пишут что mingw это не работает. Что мне делать? Надо чтобы работало на Windows а позже и на Linux

Comment: Под windows можно взять Qt для MSVC. Под линуксами gcc и clang вроде тоже могут в webengine

Comment: Поставьте кодеблок в составе с мингв, работает из коробки.

Answer (score 0):

Вобщем частично решение этого вопроса - это понизить версию Qt, тогда можно использовать webkitwidgets (я понизил до 5.4)

Comment: его выпилили после 5.5.1